Form component does not go to the next step unless it is imported dynamically with ssr as false
"use client";

import { useAuthHook } from "@/context/use-auth-context";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import SignUpForm from "./sign-up-form";

type Props = {};

// const SignUpForm = dynamic(
//   () => import("@/components/forms/sign-up/sign-up-form"),
//   {
//     ssr: false,
//   }
// );

const OTPForm = dynamic(() => import("@/components/forms/sign-up/otp-form"), {
  ssr: false,
});

export const RegistrationFormStep = (props: Props) => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
  } = useFormContext();
  const [onOTP, setOnOTP] = useState<string>("");
  const { currentStep } = useAuthHook();

  setValue("otp", onOTP);

  switch (currentStep) {
    case 1:
      return <SignUpForm errors={errors} register={register} />;
    case 2:
      return <OTPForm onOTP={onOTP} setOTP={setOnOTP} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

I am building this custom sign-up flow using Clerk authentication that renders different forms based on the current step. However, my SignUpForm component does not proceed to the next step once I click on the submit button unless I dynamically import it and set ssr to false as I did in the commented code. It validates the form and everything but does not proceed to the OTPForm which is the next step. I would love to find a way to make it work without dynamically importing it. Your help would be extremely appreciated.

Any errors in dev tools console? Both the browser one and also check the terminal next server is running in.

No errors at all, that's the weird part.
